# boost: parse json file and get a child

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to pars a JSON file with the following function:

```
std::string getFieldFromJson_data(std::string json, std::string field)
{
    std::stringstream jsonEncoded(json); // string to stream convertion
    boost::property_tree::ptree root;
    boost::property_tree::read_json(jsonEncoded, root);

    if (root.empty())
        return "";

    return (root.get<std::string>(field));
}
```

It works when reading elements like

```
device_json.data_device_id = stoi(getFieldFromJson_data(output, "data.device_id"));
```

My JSON file looks similar to:

```
 {
  "data": {
    "device_id": 67,
    "place_open": {
      "monday": [
        "10:15","19:30"
      ]
  }
}
}
```

I can read the value of "data.device_id", but when i try to read the value of "data.place_open.monday" I get an empty string.

Comment: The data behind 'monday' is not a string but a list of strings, maybe thats why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JSON library. Property Tree is not a JSON library. Using Boost JSON and JSON Pointer:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba59aa17f1695df2)**

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for header-only
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

auto getField(std::string_view json, std::string_view field) {
  return boost::json::parse(json).at_pointer(field);
}

int main() {
  auto output = R"({
    "data": {
        "device_id": 67,
        "place_open": {
            "monday": ["10:15", "19:30"]
        }
    }
})";

  for (auto pointer : {
           "/data",
           "/data/device_id",
           "/data/place_open/monday",
           "/data/place_open/monday/0",
           "/data/place_open/monday/1",
       })
    std::cout << pointer << " -> " << getField(output, pointer) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
/data -> {"device_id":67,"place_open":{"monday":["10:15","19:30"]}}
/data/device_id -> 67
/data/place_open/monday -> ["10:15","19:30"]
/data/place_open/monday/0 -> "10:15"
/data/place_open/monday/1 -> "19:30"
```

Comment: I got an error
LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_json-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_79.lib' when added headers

Comment: So, either link it, or do as I did and include `src.hpp` to use it header-only. Maybe on MSVC you need to [disable auto-link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/more/getting_started/index.html#auto-link) **or** include `src.hpp` before any other Boost JSON header, I don't know.

Comment: include src.hpp before any other Boost JSON header doesn't work. How can I disable auto-link? I use Visual Studio

Comment: I linked you to the documentation. Apparently the exact link changed, but it should be easy to find in the Windows section https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking

Comment: Sorry, I added in to a linker path to the boost and has no effect.

Comment: Works! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZ6vuO7Y4ZU here an answer how to do it

Comment: sorry again. How can I get in string variable returned value from getField? Just asign returned value to the string doesn't work.

Comment: Use serialize or some other way to do that conversion for you: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f32b94a7badcc8e or http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db73c025ea99adb3